# Selenium ChromeDriver is throwing an error "The driver executable must exist: /usr..." in AWS EC2 Ubuntu Machine

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, gitlab

I am trying to execute the Selenium script on chrome browser in AWS EC2 Ubuntu machine. The chromedriver is placed in `"/usr/local/bin"`, also I have made the file as executable by running the below command:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Please note that I am using docker as executor and GitLab Runner is installed in the above AWS EC2 Ubuntu machine.

**Below is the Selenium code to set the chromedriver path:**

```
    File file = new File("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
    System.out.println("Does file exists ? " + file.exists());
    System.out.println("Check whether file is executable : " + file.canExecute());
    System.out.println("Check whether file is readable : " + file.canRead());
    System.out.println("Check whether file is writable : " + file.canWrite());
// All the above 4 statements throws false..
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
```

**Below are the paths of the chrome-driver, google-chrome, java, docker and gitlab-runner:**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:~$ whereis chromedriver
chromedriver: /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:~$ whereis google-chrome
google-chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome /usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome.1.gz
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:~$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:~$ google-chrome -version
Google Chrome 93.0.4577.82
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:~$ chromedriver -version
ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0adeaed5550e6c7e98417dac77d98a-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#1135})
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:~$ whereis docker
docker: /usr/bin/docker /etc/docker /usr/libexec/docker /usr/share/man/man1/docker.1.gz
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:~$ whereis gitlab-runner
gitlab-runner: /usr/bin/gitlab-runner /usr/lib/gitlab-runner /etc/gitlab-runner /usr/share/gitlab-runner
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:~$ ls
chromedriver_linux64.zip  gitlab-runner_amd64.deb  google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:~$ pwd
/home/ubuntu
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:/$ pwd
/
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-94:/$ ls
bin   dev  home  lib32  libx32      media  opt   root  sbin  srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   lib64  lost+found  mnt    proc  run   snap  sys  usr
```

**Below is the console log:**

```
30652 [ERROR] testing.TC_003.bmeth[org.testng.TestRunner@64161330, org.testng.xml.XmlTest@b878032e, public void testing.TC_003.zabc() throws java.lang.InterruptedException, [Ljava.lang.Object;@609ad06b, [TestResult name={null} status=CREATED method=TC_003.zabc()[pri:0, instance:testing.TC_003@432038ec] output={null}]](0)  Time elapsed: 1.759 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist: /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
    at testing.TC_003.bmeth(TC_003.java:42)
```

**Below is the gitlab yml file:**

```
image: maven:latest

stages:
  - test

variables:
  # This will suppress any download for dependencies and plugins or upload messages which would clutter the console log.
  # `showDateTime` will show the passed time in milliseconds. You need to specify `--batch-mode` to make this work.
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"

# Cache downloaded dependencies and plugins between builds.
# To keep cache across branches add 'key: "$CI_JOB_NAME"'
cache:
  key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

test job:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker-linux
  script:
    - echo "Testing Job Triggered"
    - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS clean test
    - echo "Testing Job Finished"
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target/surefire-reports/*
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you run `file /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`?

Comment: I get `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=0c90d58f84fa8d39e9c4fd5a74d304df2fe7a593, stripped`

Comment: That part looks correct.

Comment: any idea how to resolve this issue please ?

Comment: I am not quite clear on what is your setup. What does this mean "I am using docker as executor"?

Comment: I am using GitLab with docker as executor. My GitLab runner is installed on this ubuntu machine where I have installed Docker engine on which I will use the Docker Maven container to execute the jobs. let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: It sounds like your Docker image is missing the chromedriver!

Answer (score 1):

In order for Chromedriver to work on Linux, you’ll have to install Chrome binary

```
# Install Chrome.
sudo curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add
sudo echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

**Install Xvfb** (X virtual framebuffer) witch is an in-memory display server for a UNIX-like operating system

```
sudo apt-get install -y unzip xvfb libxi6 libgconf-2-4
```

**Download Selenium Server :**

```
wget https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.13/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar
```

**Run Chrome via Selenium Server:**

```
xvfb-run java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar
```

Then you can run this python script to work with selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,
                          chrome_options=chrome_options
                         )
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
```

If it does not help, try reviewing path you provide. This exception happens whenever the chrome binary could not be found. So if you have the driver in that folder, so the problem may exists in path.

**Updated:**

Check if chromedriver is the name of the executable or folder name. You should provide name of executable file in your path.

So if the executable file in inside chromedriver directory in `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` Your code should be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/local/bin/chromedriver/chromedriver");
```

In above code the first `chromedriver` is the name of folder and the second is the name of executable file.

Comment: I have installed chrome and java open-jdk packages on AWS EC2 Ubuntu machine, but still getting the same error: `ava.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist: /usr/bin/chromedriver`

Comment: Would you please provide a picture showing result of ls command in the path.. I think there should be some problem with path. Also please provide full console error when you run the code.

Comment: I have provided the details in my post. Please let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: Check the updated part of the answer, Hope it'll be helpful

Comment: In my case, `chromedriver` is the driver file inside the `/usr/local/bin/` directory. So, the path given is `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`. Can I know how to make it executable ? I tried using `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`, how to verify whether it has become executable or not ?

Comment: If you downloaded the file for linux, it is executable by default.

Comment: I added a code in my tests to check whether the `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` file exists in the given location, then it throws false...Have updated the post with this code...

Comment: Try using this command instead : `driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")` and let me know the result

Comment: Since  am using Java, I tried providing the above path through ChromeOptions. But still it is throwing the same error...

Comment: Try these 3 steps I added to response: 1.Install Xvfb 2.Download Selenium Server 3.Run Chrome via Selenium Server. check whether chrome driver runs via selenium server

Comment: While running the chrome via Selenium Server, I get the error : `Error: Unable to access jarfile selenium-server-standalone.jar`

Comment: After running the command: `xvfb-run java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar`, it is still throwing the same error; `31746 [ERROR]   RediffLoginTest.bmeth:55 » IllegalState The driver executable must exist: /usr...`

Comment: After using RemoteWebDriver, in the URL I passed the "https://<ubuntu public ip address>:4444/wd/hub" now I am getting a different error, `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /18.118.213.92:4445 at testing.TC_003.bmeth(TC_003.java:42)`